# Android Intent response inconsistent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that is registered to receive images.  I can open the Gallery or Camera,
select an image, and in my onResume I get the ACTION_SEND intent, and all is wonderful.
If I use the Back button, I can go back to Gallery or back to the main screen and choose
a different app to send an image, and that also works.

But, if I use the Home button, then the next time the app is launched by an image Intent,
when it gets into onResume I get a MAIN intent with no image.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be overriding `onNewIntent()`, not just waiting for `onResume()`. If your activity is brought back to the foreground for a different `Intent` than what created it, `onNewIntent()` should be called, to give you that `Intent`. However, `getIntent()` *does not change* and will be some older `Intent`, whatever was used to trigger creation of the activity.